# Sharing a variable between 2 routes express

Tags: node.js, express

I wanted to know if there is a way to share variables between 2 routes in expressJS without declaring it as a global. Consider I have the following routes:

```
exports.routeOne = (req,res) => { 
 var myVariable='this is the variable to be shared';
}

exports.routeTwo = (req,res) => {
  //need to access myVariable here
}
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: Since this data presumably belongs to ONLY one user and routes can happen in any order from many users, the usual way of saving data from one route to use in a later route is to use a session manager and then you can save data on behalf of a given client from one route to the next.  You would save your data in the session and then on future route handlers, you can access all the data in the session.  And, since sessions are kept separate for separate users, your server would work appropriately for multiple users too.

Comment: I did have one additional query. What if I need to keep appending data to myVariable each time routeOne is visited ? (As in keep a tab of the previous state and then add data to it). Subsequently, I want to add that myVariable to a mongoDB in routeTwo. Would sessions work for this also ?

Comment: Yes, sessions work for that.

Comment: @jfriend00 could you provide some code snippet demonstrating as to how to use it?

Comment: See the doc for express-session on npm.  All described there.

Comment: Is this data global to the server (same value for all users) or is it user-specific so each user should have their own value of the variable?  Can you give us your real world usage (what you are actually trying to accomplish) so we can advise you better?

Comment: this data is user specific. I have a test (multiple choice and essay) that can be taken by multiple users. currently, i have a route that takes answers for multiple choice and another route for essays. currently, on each click for a multiple answer a post is made to the database. but a user can click on different options for the same question before finalising. in this, i was hoping to store the answer just once when the user completes the section instead of on every click so i just have one db query. for this, i want to use a global variable, jsonhashmap, to store answer for each question

Comment: You can use global variables to store user-specific state unless your server never had more than one user at a time.  All users will be attempting to use the exact same global variables.  That will not work.  See my answer below more more info on user sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the awesome things about NodeJS is that you can store state in variables. The process that runs your NodeJS server continues to run without restarting for each request that comes in. So any variables you store using `GLOBAL.myVarName` or variables that you store within the scope of a module (a single JavaScript file) will persist... until the process quits. The process could quit if the server goes down or if an Error or other exception is throw that is not caught. You can set up a process manager to keep it running, but your in memory variables are now lost.

I would recommend using variables that are scoped at a higher level for caching, but if the data is important it should be stored to and read from a database as needed.

Here is an example of your **routes.js** module. Any variable you declare outside of functions are scoped to this file. In other words, the variables are global to this file. You can read up more on that at https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/modules.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures.

**routes.js**

```
let variableScopedToModule = 0

exports.routeOne = (req, res) {
  variableScopedToModule++
}

exports.routeTwo = (req, res) {
  console.log(variableScopedToModule)
}
```

If it is important that you never loose the variables state, and assuming you are not running the server on multiple processes for load balancing, then you could do something like this:

**routes.js**

```
const db = require('./my-db-controller')

let cachedValue

exports.routeOne = async (req, res) {
  if (cachedValue === undefined) cachedValue = await db.getValue()
  cachedValue++
  db.setValue(cachedValue)
}

exports.routeTwo = (req, res) {
  console.log(cachedValue)
}
```

This second solution is more complex because you'll need to understand [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as well as [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Also this solution will not work if you are using a load balencer unless you use something like Redis. Alternatively you can just read and write to the database for each request instead of using in memory caching.

Comment: closures might work but I am not sure as to how to wrap all my export functions (inside the controller file) inside one higher function? Also, I am using async and await for db operations so i am familiar with those

Comment: Do you mean like this? `module.exports = function() { let cachedValue; return { routeOne: ..., routeTwo: ... } }`

Comment: This is unlikely to actually work in the real world unless the data is global (for all users) because multiple users can be using the server so data from multiple users gets mixed up.

Comment: You'd have to tie it to user sessions. Check out the NPM package "passport" for sessions.

Answer (score 3):

===============

**Note**

This answer is answering the wrong question, but it might still be useful for others who also misinterpreted the question like I did, so I'm keeping it here for now.

===============

In order for the variable to exist it would have to first execute `routeOne` and then execute `routeTwo`. This is a pretty common scenario with express. To get the details on how this works read up on middleware (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html) and understand that each route is middleware.

The common pattern solution here is to add a new property to either the `req` or `res` object that stores your variable. Then you tell the route to call the next middleware. The next middleware has access to the same `req` and `res` so it also has access to the property and value that you just stored.

There is nothing wrong with this practice as most middleware does it. For example the body-parser middleware (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Here is an example of how your code might run:

**routes.js**

```
exports.routeOne = (req,res,next) => { 
 req.myVariable='this is the variable to be shared'
 next()
}

exports.routeTwo = (req,res) => {
  //need to access myVariable here
  console.log(req.myVariable)
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes.js)

const app = express()
app.use(routes.routeOne)
app.use(routes.routeTwo)

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: It does not seem like the OP is asking about middleware.  They are asking about two completely different routes, separated by time in when they are triggered.

Comment: I did have one additional query. What if I need to keep appending data to myVariable each time routeOne is visited ? (As in keep a tab of the previous state and then add data to it). Subsequently, I want to add that myVariable to a mongoDB in routeTwo.

Comment: @AnirudhMittal If you wish to keep the state of the variable for follow up requests then you should put it into a database. Although you could store it in a variable outside of your functions there is the chance that your process will get restarted and the state of the variable lost.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes i was talking about two completely different routes

Comment: @James when you say variable outside the functions, did you mean a global variable? Also, if i were to use GLOBAL.myVariable to store the state, could that be lost too ?

Comment: Yes that can be lost too. I'll post a separate answer now that I better understand the question.

Comment: that would be helpful @James

Answer (score 0):

For user-specific data that you want to persist from one request to the next, you can't just store data in simple server-side variables because server-side variables are freely shared among all users who make requests of your server.

The usual way to store server-side data that is user-specific is to use a session object.  In a nutshell, when a user makes a request, some session middleware (which runs on every request) checks to see if a session cookie exists.  If it does not, then one is created.  The session cookie servers to uniquely identify that particular user when they make future requests.

Once you have a unique session cookie, the session middleware can create a session object that corresponds with that session cookie.  Typically, there is a unique ID in the session cookie that servers as a lookup key for the session object.

Now, whenever that user makes a request of your server, the session middleware will look at the session cookie, get the encrypted session id out of it, decrypt the id, look up the session object that corresponds to that id and then make that session object available to your request handlers, usually in `req.session`.  Your request handlers then have full access to the session object and can add, remove or modify your own properties on that session object.

[`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) is common piece of middleware that is used for implementing sessions with nodejs/express.  There are plenty of examples for how to use it in the documentation so I won't repeat that all here.  Here's [one such example in the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#reqsession).

By default, express-session uses a memory store (which just means the session objects are kept in memory).  This can be fine for simple uses, but it has some limitations and express-session does not recommend it for production use.  One major limitation of keeping the sessions in memory is that if the server crashes or restarts, all session data is lost.  There are dozens of add-in object stores for express-session, most of which store data more durably such as in a database on disk.

Comment: @Anirudh Mittal - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.